# Integration of mmenu.js in Angular

Tags: angular, mmenu

I'm trying to integrate mmenu.js in an Angular project.  It gives me a below error on the initialization.

```
 Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
```

The compiler points this line for the error

```
 new Mmenu("#mobile-menu",
```

The whole initialization code is as below :

```
new Mmenu("#mobile-menu",


                {
                  extensions    : [ 'theme-light', 'shadow-page' ],
                  wrappers: ["angular"],
                  setSelected   : true,
                  counters  : true,
                  searchfield : {
                    placeholder     : 'Search menu items'
                  },

                  sidebar       : {

                    collapsed       : {
                      use           :  '(min-width: 769px)',
                      hideNavbar        : false
                    }

                  },
                  navbars       : [

                    {
                      content       : [ 'searchfield' ]
                    }, {
                      type      : 'tabs',
                      content       : [
                        '<a href="#panel-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> <span>Menu</span></a>',
                        '<a href="#panel-account"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>Account</span></a>',
                        '<a href="#panel-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span>Cart</span></a>'
                      ]
                    }, {
                      content       : [ 'prev', 'breadcrumbs', 'close']
                    }
                  ]
                }, 

                {
                  searchfield : {
                    clear       : true
                  },
                  navbars       : {
                    breadcrumbs : {
                      removeFirst   : true
                    }
                  }
                }
              );
```

I'm pretty much sure with the required set up for mmenu.js as it is working fine under separate HTML projects. There is something that is not working correctly with the Angular.

Can someone point out what went wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably that you trigger your script before template elements are created. Try creating your menu in `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: yes, the initialization is within ngAfterViewInit() and have also tried out by using setTimeOut so that DOM is entierly rendered before initialization. but still it didn't worked.

Comment: Maybe try creating a stackblitz example.

Comment: Here is the Stackblitz URL - https://angular-sacb86.stackblitz.io

Comment: I can confirm that mmenu js main version is not working with the latest version of angular, but mmenu light is working properly. https://mmenujs.com/mmenu-light/